# why isn't the code inside head tag working when code inside body is working?

Tags: html, django

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
    {% if title %}
       <title> Django blog - {{title}} </title>
    {% else % }
       <title>  Django blog </title>
    {% endif %}
</head>
<body>

 {%  for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
    <p>By {{post.author}} on {{post.date_posted}} </p>
    <p>{{post.content}} </p>
 {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

When i run the code the head tag is empty and there is no title but the for loop executes to give the result i expected.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the head tag is _empty_? Did you check in the browsers developer tools? Does the browser tab not have the text "Django blog" atleast?

Comment: yup the head tag is completely empty <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
    
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>By anupam on August 29,2005 </p>
        <p>this is just to check </p>
    
        <h1>hi</h1>
        <p>By andy on August 28,2005 </p>
        <p>this is just to check again </p>
    
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of {% if title %}, do you mean {% if post.title %} ?

Try this-

```
<head>

{% if post.title %}
   <title> Django blog - {{post.title}} </title>
{% else % }
   <title>  Django blog </title>
{% endif %}
```

Or Make sure you have passed something called 'title' in that dictionary, like this-

```
return render(request, 'doc.html', {'post':post, 'title':title})
```

Hope my answer helped!

Comment: actually i want it to show the former one if title is passed but the latter one if no title is passed.What can i do?

Comment: You're doing it right. Just use {{ post.title }} instead of {{ title }}... Or do you mean that no title is visible in either case?